# Replacing attribute in layer's attribute table using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, attribute-table

I am automating the process of putting data collected in the field for a city's sewer system into QGis. With this script, I am trying to transfer the "tc" (top of casting, it's an elevation value) value from my GPS layer to my Structures layer. The script should be using the tc value from a highlighted GPS point and giving the highlighted structure the same tc value. My problem is in the last section (starting with struc_layer.startEditing()), where I can't figure out how to use the changeAttributeValues method to replace the tc value. The code is not raising an error, but it also isn't changing the structure's tc value in the attribute table.

Is there something different I need to do since I'm trying to edit a dictionary inside the dictionary of my attribute table?

```py
   #Saves Structure Layer
   registry = QgsProject.instance()
   struc_layer = registry.mapLayersByName('Structures')[0]

   #Saves GPS Layer
   gps_layer = registry.mapLayersByName('2019 SEASONAL MH06-25')[0]

   #Save TC value in Structure Layer as variable
   struc_selected_features = struc_layer.selectedFeatures()
   for i in struc_selected_features:
       struc_attrs = i.__geo_interface__ 
       print(struc_attrs)#Output: printed dictionary of the selected Structure 
   point's attributes!
   struc_property_values = struc_attrs.get('properties') #saves properties
   struc_tc_value = struc_property_values.get('tc') #saves TC as a variable
   struc_id = struc_property_values.get('id')

   #Save TC value in GPS Layer as variable
   gps_selected_features = gps_layer.selectedFeatures()
   for i in gps_selected_features:
       gps_attrs = i.__geo_interface__ 
       print(gps_attrs)#Prints dictionary of the selected GPS point's 
   attributes
   gps_property_values = gps_attrs.get('properties') #saves properties
   gps_tc_value = gps_property_values.get('field_4') #saves TC as a variable

   #Replaces structure's tc value with gps point's tc value
   struc_layer.startEditing()
   caps = struc_layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
   if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.ChangeAttributeValues:
       for feature in struc_property_values:
           attr_value = {4 : gps_tc_value}  #tc is the 5th key in the properties dictionary
           struc_layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({struc_id : 
   attr_value})
   struc_layer.commitChanges()
   print(struc_attrs)
```

Comment: Do both layers have a common field like an `id` field?

Comment: No, they do not, so the only way to figure out if a GPS point connects to a feature is by their proximity. The GPS points are being taken out in the field and some of them connect to structures on the Structure layer that are created already, but some GPS points don't connect to a structure yet and so a connecting structure has to be created. Due to this, in the script I'm using a single GPS point and a single structure that I've manually selected so I can connect them. I could give the GPS point an id field that matches the ID of the structure, but this would also need to be done manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just copying an attribute value from one selected feature and inserting it into a field of a selected feature in another layer, might I suggest a simpler approach to access and store those attribute fields & values which doesn't involve traversing multiple, nested dictionaries?

If know both your field names you can do this using the `lookupField()` and `attributes()` methods.

I hope you might have success with the code below:

```
_project = QgsProject().instance()
# This is the layer we are copying attributes from (your GPS Layer)
layer1 = _project.mapLayersByName('2019 SEASONAL MH06-25')[0]
layer1_feat = layer1.selectedFeatures()[0]
# get index of relevant field in first layer by its name (your 'field 4' I think)
layer1_fld_idx = layer1_feat.fields().lookupField('field_4')
# get the attribute value in that field for the selected feature
layer1_val = layer1_feat.attributes()[layer1_fld_idx]

# this is layer we are copying attributes to (your structure layer)
layer2 = _project.mapLayersByName('Structures')[0]
layer2_feat = layer2.selectedFeatures()[0]
# get id of selected feature
layer2_fid = layer2_feat.id()
# get index of field we want to copy into (your 'tc' field?)
layer2_fld_idx = layer2.fields().lookupField('tc')
# create dictionary of field index and attribute value
atts = {layer2_fld_idx: layer1_val}
# change attributes, passing the feature id and attribute map
layer2.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues({layer2_fid: atts})
```

I tested this in QGIS 3.4 with a couple of my own layers, copying elevation values between selected features.

Comment: This worked, thank you so, so much! I've been stuck on this for days!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3, you could make use of the [QgsFeature.setAttribute()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a0075d1f9c830d62c8fda6b843c307dd8) method where you just need to provide the field index of the field you're interested in and the new value you wish to assign:

```
#Replaces structure's tc value with gps point's tc value
with edit(struc_layer):
    for feature in struc_layer.getFeatures():
        feature.setAttribute(feature.fieldNameIndex('tc'), gps_tc_value)
        struc_layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

The line `with edit(struc_layer)` is essentially the `startEditing()` and `commitChanges()` methods in one. And then we iterate through each feature of `struc_layer` and set the new attribute, after which we update it.

Can't tell if this would work for your case but this is one method of changing attribute values.

Comment: When I tried this I got an error in the "with edit(struc_layer):" line, which goes away if I switch it to the struc_layer.startEditing() format, and it takes a while to run so it seems to iterate through the features, but it still does not change the tc value. I've also tried to make it just look at features that are in struc_selected_features (by putting "if feature in struc_selected_features:" as the second line), but that also didn't change it. I'm very new to coding and I'm having a hard time figuring out where I'm going wrong.